# Putty/Plink wont connect using scheduled task if im using a proxy and the user is not signed in

Tags: proxy, plink

I have a problem that i cant seem to be able solving myself. First, what do i want to achive:
Set up a scheduled taks that runs a batchfile which is connection a tunnel with a proxy in between to start a sql database sync with syncdb. All while the user that is running the scheduled task does not have to be logged in.
I have several machines that run this solution without problems, but they do not use a proxy.
The plink part of my script looks like this:
start D:\tools_putty\plink.exe -load "SessionNet" Username@IP-Address -P 22002 -pw "Password" -hostkey HOSTKEY -sshlog "D:\tools_syncdb\logs\putty\putty.log" -N -batch
If the user is logged in, everything works. But as soon as he is logged of it wont.
The setting "run wether user is logged in or not" is active.

The proxy settings are saved in the "SessionNet" Profile.
i also tried defining the proxy in the batchfile directly, but i cant seem to get it to work.

Help would be very much apreciated